# Pass string from jQuery to C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with passing string value from `jQuery` to `C#` in Web `MVC`.

There is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Account/ChangePhoneNumber',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: newPhone,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert("We returned: " + result);
    }
})
```

Here is my C# method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePhoneNumber(string data)
{                            
    return View();
}
```

While debugging `data` parameter is always null. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `data: {data: newPhone},`

Answer (score 2):

Ok I`ve figured out what was wrong:

```
 $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/Account/ChangePhoneNumber',
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: JSON.stringify({data: newPhone}),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (result) {
                                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                                }
                            })
```

I had to add  data: JSON.stringify({data: newPhone}),

Answer (score 0):

you need post your data as form object; some useful information can found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
                 $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/Account/ChangePhoneNumber',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: {data: newPhone},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert("We returned: " + result);
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: Still doesn't work is     var newPhone = $('#newPhone1').val();     this ok ?

Comment: yes if your input is <input id="newPhone1" type="text" />

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there;

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/ChangePhoneNumber',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {data: newPhone, foo: bar, fooz: barz},   //<-- mind the array here
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
                     alert("We returned: " + result);
                  }
        })
```

Which will result the following;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePhoneNumber(string data, string foo, string fooz)
{ 
    //data will contain newPhone
    //foo will contain bar
    //fooz will contain barz                           
    return View();
}
```

Just make sure to put the object in an array. So, in your case:

```
data: {data: newPhone},
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `data` correctly in ajax call. You need to pass it like this `data: {data: newPhone},`

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Account/ChangePhoneNumber',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {data: newPhone},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                 alert("We returned: " + result);
            }
        })

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ChangePhoneNumber(string data)
 {                            
      return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how you defined the route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{data}",
                defaults: new { controller = "yourcontroller", action = "actionname", data = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Please check if the parameter name in your route is "data"**

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about AJAX/JSON, you can simply use $.Post method.

```
var url = "@Url.Action("ChangePhoneNumber", "Account")";
        $.post(url, { data: newPhone })
            .fail(function() {
                // do something
            })
            .done(function(result) {
                alert("We returned: " + result);
            });
```